# Determine sobject Type From Id Using SOAP API

Tags: soql, api, soap-api, sobject, c#

I'm using C# and would like to determine the type of an sObject based on it's `id`.

I would like to pass an `id` to my app and have it return a list of accounts related to it. I need to identify the sobject type of the `id` so I can create a proper soql query for it. (If it's an `Invoice__c` do one query, if it's a `Crazy_Custom_Grandchild__c` do another, etc...)

I tried a [.search()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_search.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_search.htm|SkinName=webhelp) api call like this:

```
FIND {'001800000116UUiAAM'} IN Id FIELDS RETURNING Contact(Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName), 
Lead(Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName), Account(Id, Phone, Name)
```

but received a malformed query error because of the `id` field.

I don't want to have to do a whole bunch of `try ... catch` calls, there has to be a better way...

Comment: Okay, so let me get this right. Do you want to return the sObject type? or do you want related records?

Comment: I want determine sobject type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

best solution I've come up with so far is to use [.describeGlobal()](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_search.htm%7CStartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_search.htm%7CSkinName=webhelp) like this:

```
DescribeGlobalResult dgr = binding.describeGlobal();
DescribeGlobalSObjectResult dgsr = dgr.sobjects.FirstOrDefault(x =>
    string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.keyPrefix) ? false : id.StartsWith(x.keyPrefix));

    if (dgsr != null)
    {
        switch (dgsr.name)
        {
            case "custom1__c":
                ...
                break;
            case "custom2__c":
                ...
                break;
            case "custom3__c":
                ...
                break;
            default:
                ...
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is what I followed in **Apex**, I am not too sure how will it work in the **SOAP API**

1. Create a Map of Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
2. Now, key will be the first 3 letters of the ID and value will be sObject Name

Follow some Code:

```
//Suppose accId is a string which holds an Id    
String keyCode  = accId.subString(0,3);

//Create a Map
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

//Iterate over all the Map Values
for(Schema.SObjectType objectInstance : gd.values()){
     if(objectInstance.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix() == keyCode){
      //do your processing with the API name what you want
      System.debug('Id is related to object: '+ objectInstance.getDescribe().getName());
     }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but I want to do this using `C#` / `SOAP API` in an external application running on my own server, not `Apex`. Both our answers are conceptually along the same lines though...

Comment: Not a C# developer. Sorry mate, but goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this more efficiently now with the SOAP versions of the Tooling API via [EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm). There is a `KeyPrefix` field you can search on to find the specific match.

E.g.

```
Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition where KeyPrefix = '001'
```

Answer (score 0):

WSC + JAVA The best solution

```
String recordId = '00163000009j310';
String prefix = recordId.substring(0, 3);

String sobjectType = null;
for (DescribeGlobalSObjectResult sobj : connection.describeGlobal().getSobjects()){
    if (sobj.getKeyPrefix() != null) {
        if (sobj.getKeyPrefix().equals(prefix)){
            sobjectType = sobj.getName();
        }
    }
}
```