# How to find type of an hardcoded ID in JAVA

Tags: apex, soap-api, metadata, salesforce-id, tooling-api

In SFDC we have methods to identify the  type of ID

Sample code:

```
Id idType = '50011000002ZXX';               
Schema.sObjectType entityType = idType.getSObjectType();  
System.debug('ID belongs to:'+entityType); //ID belongs to: Case
```

Can we make use of the above methods in Java code using an API? How would one access these methods?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with either the SOAP or REST based versions of the Tooling API via [EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm). There is a `KeyPrefix` field you can search on to find the specific match.

E.g.

```
Select Id,QualifiedApiName,KeyPrefix from EntityDefinition where KeyPrefix = '001'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the generated code you are using to connect to Salesforce to determine if the Id type is a basic string type, or an actual type with methods associated with it.

From [Metdata API Field Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm):

> "Note that most Web services tools, including .NET andWSC, map the ID simple type defined in the API WSDL (Enterprise or Partner) to a string. However, other tools generate a specific ID class to represent the ID simple type. Please consult your Web services toolkit documentation for more information."

---

See this (Near duplicate) for examples on how to determine the type of an id in non-apex code:

[Determine sobject Type From Id Using SOAP API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/11280/determine-sobject-type-from-id-using-soap-api)